# Virtual Machine failover with KVM

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, webserver

I'm trying failover of VM's in KVM Linux as a learning program.

Scenario:

2 HV Bare metal  (2 physical servers) having CentOS with KVM.
On both the HV there are multiple web-server with guest Windows 2008 R2 with MSSQL DB running on it.

- MSSQL Server 2005 Management studio
- Centos 6 or 7 with KVM

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Not looking for purchase or invest for making it work.
There is no storage connected to this environment.

Comment: have you thought `VM Clustering` without storage I think it wont work.

Comment: Take a look at [Ganeti](http://www.ganeti.org/) - a cluster VM manager that can make clever use of LVM+DRBD for shared-storage failover.

Comment: Thanks CAS, or this link. You understood my requirement. I will try and implement it soon.